# How do I show a HTML tag only when Express view engine passes a value?

Tags: express, handlebars.js, ejs, viewengine

If you see the code below, you'll notice that for GET request, 'add' page does not get any value passed, whereas for POST request, 'add' page gets 'msg' value as a result of posting.

```
router.get('/add', (req, res) => {
  res.render('add', {})
})

router.post('/add', (req, res) => {
  // receive a form 
  // save it to the database
  // Promise is returned
  .then(gig => res.render('add', {
    msg: 'Your application is successful.'
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }
 })
```

In **add.ejs** file, I am not allowed to write *<%= msg %>*  because it will cause an error for GET requests. Is there any other way than passing a { msg: null } to the GET router?

```
router.get('/add', (req, res) => {
      res.render('add', { msg: null })
})
```

I'm asking this because I think passing null for cases like this is very repetitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the alternative would be adding a control in the file you want to render

<% var msg = msg ?? null %>

this way if the variable *msg* isn't passed the value is null and the field will be empty

Comment: Brilliant idea! is double question mark an EJS tag for ternary operator?

Comment: the double question mark is part ECMAScript specification , you can read more about it here   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator


If you're using node and ejs server-side, the ECMAScript version is based on node version

Comment: Thanks. I only knew how to use && to this date. ;)